# Beautifulsoup can't extract src attribute from img tag

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
html = '''<img onload='javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950'
src="http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
imgs = soup.findAll('img')

print imgs[0].attrs
```

It will print `[(u'onload', u'javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950')]`

So where is the `src` attribute?

If I replace html by something like `html = '''<img src="/image/fluffybunny.jpg" title="Harvey the bunny" alt="a cute little fluffy bunny" />'''`

I get correct results as `[(u'src', u'/image/fluffybunny.jpg'), (u'title', u'Harvey the bunny'), (u'alt', u'a cute little fluffy bunny')]`

I am quite new to HTML and beautifulsoup. Am I missing some knowledge? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this with both versions three and four of BeautifulSoup, and noticed that `bs4` (version 4) seems to fix up your HTML better than version 3.

With BeautifulSoup 3:

```
>>> html = """<img onload='javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950' src="http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg">"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # Version 3 of BeautifulSoup
>>> print soup
<img onload="javascript:if(this.width&gt;950) this.width=950" />950) this.width=950' src="http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg"&gt;
```

Notice how `>` is now `&gt;` and some bits are out of place.

Also, when you call BeautifulSoup(), it kind of splits it up. If you were to print soup.img, you would get:

```
<img onload="javascript:if(this.width&gt;950) this.width=950" />
```

And so you would miss details.

With `bs4` (BeautifulSoup 4, the current version):

```
>>> html = '''<img onload='javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950' src="http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg">'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
>>> print soup
<html><body><img onload="javascript:if(this.width&gt;950) this.width=950" src="http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg"/></body></html>
```

Now with `.attrs`: In BeautifulSoup 3, it returns a list of tuples, as is what you have discovered. In BeautifulSoup 4, it returns a dictionary:

```
>>> print soup.findAll('img')[0].attrs # Version 3
[(u'onload', u'javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950')]

>>> print soup.findAll('img')[0].attrs # Version 4
{'onload': 'javascript:if(this.width>950) this.width=950', 'src': 'http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg'}
```

So what to do? [Get BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download). It will parse the HTML much better.

By the way, if all you want is just the `src`, calling `.attrs` is not needed:

```
>>> print soup.findAll('img')[0].get('src')
http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw600/c3107d40jw1e3rt4509j.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the superb answer and all the details. I did not configure SO to auto-send replies to my email so I read this late. I installed bs4 and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be useful:

```
image=container.find("div",{"class":"ika-picture-flex-box"})
image=image.find_all("source")
image[1].get('srcset')
```